# ASP.NET MVC 5 и авторизация в БД Oracle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

У меня есть БД Oracle 10g R2 и толстый клиент написанный на Delphi 6, есть желание сделать web client на ASP.NET MVC 5, для начала хочу создать авторизацию и вывод личной информации с личного кабинета, так как  авторизация сделана в тостом клиенте с помощью встроенной Oracle пользователей есть затруднение прикрутить эту авторизацию к ASP.NET MVC, не могли подсказать как это сделать или может уже существуют готовые библиотеки?

Я работаю с базой через Oracle.ManagedDataAccess и Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework!

Comment: А что у вас уже получилось до сих пор?

Comment: пока нет, ищу варианты!)

Comment: Как нет? Вы же пишете - "Я работаю с базой через Oracle.ManagedDataAccess и Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework".

Comment: если вы это имеете виду, то да)
я подумал за авторизацию пользователей!

Comment: Ну вот, вы нашли [например что-то](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-managed-nuget-121021-2405792.txt), попробовали и что-то не получается. А что не получается?

Comment: Это я все сделал и оно работает уже) Хотелось узнать бы как прикрутить авторизацию по отдельнныйм пользователям!?

Comment: А что такое "отдельный пользователь"? Вы имеете ввиду не пользователей БД, а пользователей сохранённых в БД?

Comment: в моем случае "отдельный пользователь" это пользователь БД со своими ролями и точкой входа в дереве подраздилений!

Comment: Воозьмите лучше Oracle Apex. Авторизация по пользователям БД там есть "из коробки". Ну и вообще всё намного проще, программировать почти не нужно. Попробовать можно тут: apex.oracle.com

Comment: @Dmitry, долго прийдется перелазить, просто много чего написано на c#, я так понимаю что Oracle Apex больше заточен под Java!

Comment: Oracle Apex заточен под PL/SQL ;). Но раз куча на C# уже написана, то да, сложно перелезать будет.

Comment: прийдется какой то велосипед изобретать)